# Deleting and inserting a score into a text file form python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I have created a text based game in python 3.3 were users pick a class for their character. I want the game to store three scores so an average can be taken. My problem is that i am unsure how to get the program to search for a name in the file and delete there oldest score, This is what the file where the scores are saved looks like:

```
Bennie
33
62
94
Josh
82
55
31
Jackie
10
4
3
```

My current code that sees if they have done the game before and if not writes there score to the file if they have i have got the code to split the lines and read them. It needs to delete the score closet to their name and insert and new score just before the next name but i am unsure how to do this. This is my current code

```
    class_choice = input('Enter Class one, Class two or Class three.')
    if class_choice == "One":
        text_file = 'class1.txt'
    elif class_choice == "Two":
        text_file = 'class2.txt'
    elif class_choice == "Three":
        text_file = 'class3.txt'
    else:
        False
    first_time = input('Is this the first you have completed this game: Yes or No?')
    if first_time == 'Yes':
        with open(text_file, "a") as file:
            file.write("{}\n".format(name))
            file.write("0\n")               
            file.write("0\n")   
            file.write("{}\n".format(score))                
            sys.exit()
    else:
        file = open(text_file, 'r')
        lines = file.read().splitlines()
```

Comment: I think if you want to use a file try [config](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) it will be much easier to append and extract data.

Comment: Are you restricted to use just files? Is this a small program that would never grow? You could use a DB like sqlite3 if you didn't have above problems.

Comment: The program is small so will not grow

Comment: If this is a homework assignment Nasher may not be permitted to use things like `config` or a database, even if they knew how to use such things in Python.

Comment: @PM2Ring is correct i am not allowed to use config and databases so i must stick to a .txt file. It is not homework just a task i have been set hence i am allowed to use stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

giving a sample python method to add a score to the file (pseudo-code) modify as needed to suit your needs (your requirement is not the most efficient method):

```
def add_score(user, score, text_file):
    lines = text_file.splitlines()
    count = len(lines)
    user_exists = False
    user_index = -1
    num_scores = 3
    user_num_scores = 0
    for i in range(count-1):
        line = lines[i]
        if user == line:
            # user previous scores start after here
            user_exists = True
            user_index = i
            break

    if not user_exists:
        # user does not exist, create by appending
        lines.append(user)  
        lines.append(str(score)) 
    else: # user exists, fix the scores 
        j=1
        while j <= num_scores:
            line = lines[user_index+j]
            j += 1
            if line.isdigit():
               # user score line
               user_num_scores +=1
        if user_num_scores == num_scores:
            for i in range(1,num_scores-1): lines[user_index+i] = lines[user_index+i+1] # shift up
            lines[user_index+num_scores] = str(score) # add the latest score  
        else: # just append/insert the score, as the previous scores are less than num_scores
            lines.insert(user_index+user_num_scores, str(score))

    return "\n".join(lines)   # return the new text_file back
```

use like this:

```
text = file.read()
updated_text = add_score('UserName', 32, text)
```

**Note** the function given will **not change the file** it will just operate on the given **file contents** (as `text_file` argument). This is on purpose since if the function itself manipulated the files it would limit its use, since one can read or write the file in any convenient instant for the whole application. So this function only operates on strings. This is **not the most efficient method**, for example one can use a file per user and a much simpler format, but since this what is asked for this answer covers only that.

When you have finished adding scores and manipulating the files, you can update the file by writing the `updated_text` back to it. (Probably if the file is already opened in `read` mode, you will have to close it and re-open it in `write` mode).

To write (update) the file with the new contents use sth like this:

```
file.write(updated_text)
```

for example see [here for python file I/O operations](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_write.htm)

Comment: Thanks for this i copied it my code where it is needed but it does not seem to do anything i get to the part when  it should run but it does nothing to the file it seem and loops back to asking me my class again so i assume it is getting to the break and looping back to my while true: is there a way to stop that

Comment: @Nasher, the file is not changed by the function, you should re-write the `updated_text` back to the file, in order to change the file. The function accepts the **contents of the file** and returns the updated contents, you should write them back to the file again to update the file

Comment: @Nasher, i'll be offline for a while but feel free to post a comment if further clarification is needed. As mentioned the solution and scheme you use **is not the most efficient** For example you could have a file per user and a much simpler format. But since this is what you asked i gave this answer

Comment: Sorry if this is really basic and i sound stupid but how would i write it to the file again. @Nikos M

Comment: @Nasher, it's ok, check for example [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_write.htm). You can check the python I/O file methods, like you already use the `.read` method

Comment: @Nasher, if you have opened the file for reading you should probably close it first and then open it again for writing (and so on). As reading and writing files requires different uses of the underlying operating system. The function i gave in answer does not write the file on purpose since that would limit its use. The user may read or write the file at any instant it is more convenient for the whole application

Comment: I have a basic understanding of how to use the file.write function but i am confused and how to add it to the code you have given . would you be able to edit the answer so i can see how it work . Thanks again for you much appreciated help

Comment: @Nasher, updated answer. Hope it helps, you will certainly have to update your knowledge of python basic methods and I/O functions as this answer cannot cover all this ground

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change a single line inside a file. You can only append content at the end of the file or override the entire content.
If you wat to store the scores on a file, you need to read the file line by line storing each line in an auxiliar variable (concatenating lines) and when you reach the line you need to modify, concatenate the modified line into the auxiliar variable. Then keep reading the file line by line and storing it into the auxiliar variable. 
When done, write down the content of the auxiliar variable in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try creating an .ini file and store your data in the attributes under sections. It's framework suits your requirements. It kind-of works like an xml file, but since your input and output parameters are limited (as you mentioned; 3 scores), it seems like the best option to opt for. Simply go through ini file manipulation using python in python docs and you will know what to do. Cheers !

Answer (score -1):

> My problem is that i am unsure how to get the program to search for a name in the file and delete there oldest score

I would create several .txt (or .dat) files with the name "< class >_stats[.txt]" (without the spaces, obviously). From there:

```
class_choice = raw_input("Choose your class")
# if needing stats
f = open("%s_stats.txt" % class_choice, "r+")
lines = f.readlines()  
f.close()

stats = [float(i) for i in lines]  # i.e. [3, 5.5, 4]

# rest of game
# overwrite with new stats
new_stat = get_new_stat()
f = open("%s_stats.txt" % class_choice, "w")
f.write("\n".join([str(i) for i in stats]))
```

However, I would recommend just keeping the stats, you may want them later, and text is cheap. Instead of reading all lines, simply open the file for appending, read the last three, and append the new stat to the end when you get your new stat, i.e.

```
f = open("%s_stats.txt")
lines = f.readlines[-3:]  # reads last 3
f.close()
# stuff
f = open("%s_stats.txt", "a")
f.write(get_new_stat())
f.close()
```

Comment: Your code doesn't deal with the names in the files. Also, the scores are `int`, not `float`.